# C++ WINSOCKS2 Совместное использование Connect и Bind

Tags: c++, windows, winsock2

Мне необходимо, чтобы сокет отправлял данные с определённой локальной конечной точки. Однако вызов `connect` после вызова `bind` даёт ошибку `WSAENETUNREACH` (Network is unreachable). Видимо я делаю что то не так. Как исправить?

```
WSADATA wsaData;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != NO_ERROR)
{
    return -1;
}

SOCKET streamSocket;
streamSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (streamSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

SOCKADDR_IN localAddr = { 0 };
localAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
localAddr.sin_port = htons(iPort);
if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &localAddr.sin_addr) != 1)
{
    closesocket(streamSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

if (bind(streamSocket, (PSOCKADDR)&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    closesocket(streamSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr = { 0 };
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(iDestPort);
if (inet_pton(AF_INET, lpszIp, &serverAddr.sin_addr) != 1)
{
    closesocket(streamSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

if (connect(streamSocket, (PSOCKADDR)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "Connect error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    closesocket(streamSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Со 127.0.0.1 вряд ли можно достучаться куда-либо, кроме 127.0.0.1

Comment: Так это IP указываемый в `bind`. В `connect` передаётся `lpszIp`, содержащий адрес удалённого хоста.

Comment: Убрал установку `localAddr.sin_addr` - всё заработало. Благодарю за решение

Comment: Если не установить `localAddr.sin_addr`, то это будет биндинг к 0.0.0.0

Comment: Да. И это сработало для меня. Такого не должно быть?

Comment: Ну в вопросе написано "чтобы сокет отправлял данные с определённой локальной конечной точки", а биндинг к 0.0.0.0 по сути ничего не делает - это поведение по-умолчанию.

Comment: Но указывается порт. Мне это и нужно. С другого компьютера в сети происходит встречное подключение (тот же код). Таким образом, чтобы всё получилось, сокет должен ожидать ответа на определённый порт. Это подобно идее TCP Hole Punching, только там нет необходимости привязывать сокеты к определённым портам - порты становятся известны благодаря серверу в нужный момент.